# How to fully qualify a var's value?

Tags: clojure

Imagine that:

```
(def my-var 'my-symbol)  ;; Please note that it must be 'my-symbol not `my-symbol

my-var ;; => my-symbol
```

But I want

```
;; => fully-qualified/my-symbol
```

Other than converting values to strings, is it possible to fully qualify my-var's value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since symbols are created from strings (see [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L46)) and they are immutable, in order to build a fully qualified symbol from a symbol a conversion to String is inevitable.

```
(symbol (name (ns-name *ns*)) (name 'my-symbol))
```

Keywords are also able to be fully qualified. The value `::my-keyword` will be expanded by the reader to be fully qualified, taking the namespace where the value is being read.

```
::my-keyword
;;= :user/my-keyword
(ns other-ns)
::my-keyword
;;= :other-ns/my-keyword
```

They are more broadly used in Clojure when you need fully qualified values.

Answer (score 5):

Use a back quote instead of a straight quote:

```
(def my-var `my-symbol) ; and not 'my-symbol
```

Comment: thanks cgrand, but i did comment that it must be 'my-symbol and not `my-symbol